# Adding something to the DOM with JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to make it so when you click a 'card' element,visible on the page,the classes show and open to be added,so you can see the card symbol. Anyone has any ideea why it doesn't work,i've selected it but it seems like it won't work...
Like  i am selecting,iterating throught the card array adding to each card an event listener and toggling the class,why wouldn't it work?

I have this html

```js
let card = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
let cards = [card];

// whenever something unexpected is going on 
// that operates on/with a variable of yours
// do this:
console.log(typeof cards);

for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  cards[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("open");
    this.classList.toggle("show");
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Matching Game</h1>
  </header>

  <section class="score-panel">
    <ul class="stars">
      <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
    </ul>

    <span class="moves">3</span> Moves

    <div class="restart">
      <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
    </div>
  </section>

  <ul class="deck">
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Pick your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("card")` returns an array, so your `card` variable is already an array. `let cards = [card];` adds your array to another array.

This is why your for loop does nothing. Try this instead:

```
let cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

for (i=0;i < cards.length;i++) {
  cards[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.classList.toggle("open");
    this.classList.toggle("show");
  });
}
```

Comment: *returns an array* - no, it returns an Array-**like** HTMLCollection.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just go

```
let cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
```

and remove the line saying

```
let cards = [card];
```

```js
let cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  cards[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("open");
    this.classList.toggle("show");
  });
}
```

```css
.deck {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
}

.open::before {
  content: "o"
}

.show::after {
  content: "s";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Matching Game</h1>
  </header>

  <section class="score-panel">
    <ul class="stars">
      <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
    </ul>

    <span class="moves">3</span> Moves

    <div class="restart">
      <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
    </div>
  </section>

  <ul class="deck">
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If for some reason you want to cast your `HTMLCollection` that returns from `document.getElementsByClassName("card")` to a native `Array`, use `Array.from`:

```
let card = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
let cards = Array.from(card); // or [...card]
```